# Visual Studio 2010 - TFS - Cant remove workspace, error fully-qualified username

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, workspace, fully-qualified-naming

So i have an Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Team Foundation installation on my laptop that has corrupted Workspaces. I have tried to do a full cleanup but i cant get these Workspaces to reset or whatever.

The problem is that the WorkSpaceOwner isnt my actual account name but some kind of random ID. I cant delete the Workspaces, nor can I select the right user account. It keeps giving me these kind of errors:

While trying to remove the workspace:
-The user name [ID] is not a fully-qualified user name. Parameter name: workspaceOwner.

[ERROR Message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXMqE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair your VS2010 by installing the updates in the following order:

- [Visual Studio 2010 SP 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20506)
- [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)
- [Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34677)

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?